# Send vars to iframe loaded into extjs window widget

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, window, widget

I have this code in Extjs

```
function showPlayer(params)
{
// params is an array of parameters sent to the iframe

    win = Ext.create('widget.window',
    {
        title: "Call player",
         width: 735,
        height: 280,
        ghost: false,
         modal: false,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        items: [
        ],

        html: '<iframe src="somepage.php?callId='+params[0]+'&lang='+params[11]+'"    style="width: 720px; height: 240px; border: none;"></iframe>'
    });

    win.on('close', function(){
       //close current tab in browser (doesn't works in FF)
       //window.close();
   });

   //show window event
    win.show(this, function(){

    })
}
```

My question is how to sen the values from params array to the iframe contentWindow trough extjs window widget?  Any idea?

Two of the params array 0 and 11 are sent trough url other 8 makes no sense to send them trough url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar recently, I couldn't find any ExtJs specific functions. I settled for naming a parameter array in the parent document as a global variable. Then I just called `parent.myParameterArray` from within the iFrame to scoop up the parameters.